# Grabbing numbers from a string if it starts with a certain letter

Tags: c#

I'm hoping someone here can help me with this. If I have a string that starts with the Letter "S" and is followed by a number that's up to 8 digits long, is it possible to grab the digits afterwards?

So let's say if I have a string "blah blah blah blah S124 blah", how can I put the 124 in an int variable?

Comment: Please include your code in the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with regular expressions (Regex).

In this case, it would be something like:

```
// Matches letter S and numbers from 1 up to 8 times and encapsulates numbers in group
S(\d{1,8})
```

And you could extract from the Match for getting the digits.

```
Regex numberRegex = Regex(regexString);
Match m = numberRegex.Match(stringToMatch);

String onlyNumbers = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

After that convert it to numbers

```
int number = int.Parse(onlyNumbers)
```

Comment: Beware that such regex will also match if it's in the middle of something, like `CODES15BAD`. If you need to avoid such strings you can add a word boundary: `\bS(\d{1,8})\b`. Of course, remember to use `@` before the string literal for the backslashes to work (otherwise you will need to duplicate them, and for regexes it's usually annoying).

Comment: @Andrew so the pattern would look like `@\bS(\d{1,8})\b` ?

Comment: @profiter, the @ is not part of the regex, but denotes a "verbatim string", so either `string regexString = @"\bS(\d{1,8})\b"` or equivalently `string regexString = "\\bS(\\d{1,8})\\b"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to avoid groups

```
Regex.Match(input,@"(?<=S)\d{1,8}\b").Value;
```

Comment: Like with the other answer, beware this matches stuff like `CODES15BAD`, not sure if @profiter wants that.